# jQuery - Local Storage sort stringified object order

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have an object `menuItems` which is JSON stringified (contains 3 objects in it) and is saved in localstorage. It comes back as `result` from the server.

```
localStorage.setItem('menuItems', JSON.stringify(result));
```

The 3 objects in `menuItems` are:

```
{
    id: "1"
    item: "Apple",
    type: "fruit"
},
{
    id: "2"
    item: "Banana",
    type: "fruit"
},
{
    id: "3"
    item: "Carrot",
    type: "vegetable"
}
```

I get `menuItms` from local storage, loop over its objects, and get the below list in the same order it comes above, which is perfect. I want to sort them though, and resave the new order to localstorage, so when looping over them, I output the index for each iteration in the data-sort-id.

```
<ul class="sort-menu-items-list">
    <li data-sort-id="0">Apple is a fruit</li>
    <li data-sort-id="1">Banana is a fruit</li>
    <li data-sort-id="2">Carrot is a vegetable</li>
</ul>
```

After sorting them on the front end, I get the following as the final sort order. I want to resave the object `menuItems` in local storage, to always retrieve them in this new order:

```
<ul class="sort-menu-items-list">
    <li data-sort-id="2">Carrot is a vegetable</li>
    <li data-sort-id="0">Apple is a fruit</li>
    <li data-sort-id="1">Banana is a fruit</li>
</ul>
```

How can I save the new 2, 0, 1 sort order for `menuItems` objects to local storage, so when I retrieve `menuItems` it comes out in that new order? I think the `data-sort-id` should help somehow, but not sure how to proceed with resaving the new order to local storage. Any idea?

UPDATE:

```
$('.sort-done').click(function(){
    var newSortIds = [];
    $('.sort-menu-items-list').find('li').each(function(){
       newSortIds.push($(this).data('sort-id'));
    });
    console.log(newSortIds); // ["2","0","1"]
});
```

What would I need to add to the above code to make it work in jQuery?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2NtS/294/

Comment: have u tried localStorage.removeItem('menuItems') before you persist it?

Comment: hmm, no, but not sure how that would help.. The data-sort-id is basically an index value, I output when looping over the li's. I rearrange them to have a rearranged list of sort-id (which are unrelated to the menuItems) I am able to create a new array list of ids by looping over each li, and pushing its sort-id to a new array `sortedIds`, but I'm not sure how to apply the `sortedIds` order, to match the order in the `menuItems` array and resave the `menuItems` with that new order.

Comment: would it be too cumbersome to recreate the object based on the results of  the sorting and then overwrite `menuItems` in localStorage?

Comment: @lucas, the results come from the server, so I just want to attach the sort id to them and "resave" them in that order, so when I pull from local storage, it is in that new order.. Not sure how though (codewise) based on my above sort order..

Comment: if menuItems is an array, you can just loop though your li's after sort, push  the `data-sort-id` s to another array, then on page load loop through your menuItems and render them to the li using a querySelectorAll and the index that you get from the data-sort-id array. Dunno if I make myself clear or you need a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the below strategy solve your problem?

1. Load menuItems from server.
2. Add sort_key attribute to each item of menuItems.
3. Save menuItems in localstrage.
4. Load menuItems from localstrage.
5. Sort menuItems by sort_key.
6. Render menuItems in HTML.
7. (A User sort on the front end)
8. Renumber sort_key attribute to each item of menuItems depending on user sort result.
9. Save menuItems in localstrage.

You need to decide an event when you renumber and save to localstrage. For example when user click sort button or when user click some save button and so on.

The code is something like below.

```
function loadFromServer(){
    // This is mock code.
    return [
        {
            id: "1",
            item: "Apple",
            type: "fruit"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            item: "Banana",
            type: "fruit"
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            item: "Carrot",
            type: "vegetable"
        }
    ];
}

function loadFromLocalstrage(){
    // This is mock code.
    return [
        {
            id: "2",
            item: "Banana",
            type: "fruit",
            sort_key: 2
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            item: "Carrot",
            type: "vegetable",
            sort_key: 3
        },
        {
            id: "1",
            item: "Apple",
            type: "fruit",
            sort_key: 1
        }
    ];
}

function addSortKeyAtt(items){
    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++){
        var item = items[i];
        item.sort_key = i;
    }
}

function sortByKey(items){
    return items.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.sort_key - b.sort_key;
    });
}

function userOperation(items){
    // This is mock code.
    var item0 = items[0],
        item1 = items[1],
        item2 = items[2];
    return [
        item2, item0, item1
    ];
}


// #1
var menuItems = loadFromServer();
// #2
addSortKeyAtt(menuItems);
// #3
// Save to localstrage.
// #4
menuItems = loadFromLocalstrage();
// #5
menuItems = sortByKey(menuItems);
// #6
// Render menuItems in HTML.
// #7
menuItems = userOperation(menuItems);
// #8
addSortKeyAtt(menuItems);
// #9
// Save to localstrage.

console.log(menuItems);
```

UPDATE:

If you want to integrate it in your jquery code, this would help you.
Although I wrote thie sample, I recommend you to separete managing model data logic from manupulating DOM logic as much as possible.

```
var menuItems = [
    {
        id: "1",
        item: "Apple",
        type: "fruit",
        sort_key: 1
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        item: "Banana",
        type: "fruit",
        sort_key: 2
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        item: "Carrot",
        type: "vegetable",
        sort_key: 3
    }
];

$('.sort-done').click(function(){
    var newMenuItems = [];
    $('.sort-menu-items-list').find('li').each(function(i){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        // To make code simple, I use underscorejs find function. You could implement the same code if you don't want use underscorejs.
        var item = _.find(menuItems, function(item){
            return item.id === id.toString();
        });
        item.sort_key = i + 1;
        newMenuItems.push(item);
    });
    console.log(newMenuItems);
});
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/s5r20dro/3/)

UPDATE:

If you don't want to use underscorejs, you can write your find function quite easily. The code would be something like this.

```
function find(array, iteratee){
    for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++){
        var item = array[i];
        if (iteratee(item)){
                return item;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

[jsfiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/D2NtS/300/)

I hope this would help you.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, but not sure how to do it in code. How do I do #2, add a sort key into each of the items. And how to sort by them when outputting them?

Comment: OK. I will try to write sample code to achieve #2 later.

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around it, it's definitely what I am tryng to accomplish but not sure how to integrate it into the working jquery loop above on each menu item. I am sorry for not mentioning that before the update.. I am able to output the new sort order of the rearranged menu items, as shown in console above, but not integrate it back into local storage for output... Thank you for your effort thus far, but please let me know if you're able to get it to work with what I got so far in jquery..

Comment: yazaki, I added a fiddle with the exact issue ready.. The issue is I don't have that the sort_key in my default array. Can you take a look please?

Comment: Is this what you want? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/D2NtS/297/)  Click done button and check your browser console.

Comment: Thank you yazaki. I don't use underscore for _.find, anyway it can be changed to each/push somehow?

Comment: yazaki, exactly what I was after, thank you for the ongoing help from javascript to jquery and underscore to a function!

Comment: I appriciate to hear that. And thank you for your acceptance of my answer!

Answer (score 1):

something like this may help

```js
var fruits = [{
  id: "1",
  item: "Apple",
  type: "fruit"
}, {
  id: "2",
  item: "Banana",
  type: "fruit"
}, {
  id: "3",
  item: "Carrot",
  type: "vegetable"
}];

var sortorder = [2, 0, 1]; // get this from localStorage

var i = 0,
  list = document.querySelectorAll("li"),
  len = fruits.length;

for (i; i < len; i++) {
  var ord = sortorder[i];
  list[i].innerHTML = fruits[ord].item + " is a " + fruits[ord].type;
  list[i].setAttribute("data-sort-id", ord);
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  var ord = [];
  var a = 0;

  for (a; a < len; a++) {
    ord.push(Number(list[a].getAttribute("data-sort-id")))
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify(ord)) // set this to localStorage
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="get order">
```

Comment: sorry, I just realized I didn't include jquery and trying to build off of it. Not sure how to integrate your code into it to return the entire object sorted with the new order. I am able to output the new sort order of the rearranged menu items, as shown in console above, but not integrate it back into local storage for output...

Comment: you don't need to re-order the object - just save the order of the sort into local storage (instead of  `alert(JSON.stringify(ord))` ) once the sorting is done and check for its existence on page load. You don't need jQuery for any of that.

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you what you're looking for:

```
$('.sort-done').click(function(){
    var newSortIds = $.makeArray($('.sort-menu-items-list-sorted-unsaved > li').map(function(i, e) {
        return $(e).data('sort-id');
    }));
    var outputArray = $.makeArray($(menuItems).map(function(i, e) {
        return $(menuItems).filter(function(index, element) { 
           return parseInt(element.id) == parseInt(newSortIds[i]);
        })[0];
    }));
});
```

One thing to note is the outputArray is just an array of objects like the initial menuItems array. I assume you know how you would populate the ul from that. If you don't just let me know.

Here's some links to some functions I used:

makeArray(): https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

map(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Here's your JSFiddle edited to use the functions I listed above and also displaying the output on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/D2NtS/298/

Comment: I have no issue getting the new sort ids, I am just stuck on sorting the default list in the new sort ids order. So the default data sort order is 1,2,3, I rearrange them to the new sort ids ["2","0","1"], or if we forget the index and just rearrange based on the ids it will be ["3","1","2"]. But with that new order of sort ids, how can I make that the new display order using it as the new way to sort by data-sort-id?

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and have updated my comment to what I think it is you're looking for. If it's not let me know and I'll take another look.

Comment: Hi Thomasov, looks good, but is it possible to only use each and push for something like this to get the same end result? For each newSortId, push the matching menuItem. Or render the menu items, sorted based on this newSortId order?

Comment: Do you need to use an each and push for a specific reason? This returns the same result. If you need help rendering the items I can help you with that, but I probably wouldn't change the newSortId unless you had a reason to.

Comment: I modified your fiddle to add new sorted output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101800/discussion-between-thomasov-and-wonka).

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help Thomasov. Upvoted and definitely a great answer that gets the job done. I am sure it will help many others out there! Yazaki and I have been going at it for a while as well, and he went from a javascript example which I asked for initially to a jquery when I changed it so I granted him the bounty. Thank you for all the help again man, great solution!!

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it solved. Best of luck to you on the rest of the project.